# Как удалить столбцы, у которых кол-во пропущенных значений больше 2 согласно прилагаемого алгоритма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Алгоритм удаления по заданию следующий:

1. найдите все такие столбцы (метод `.isna()` + подвыборка с условием)
2. определите их названия (поймите как выцепить названия и сохраните их в массив, т.е. по цепочке примените методы `.index`, `.tolist()` или `.values`)
3. "дропните их" (используйте метод `.drop` (имена столбцов))
4. результат сохраните в новой табличке (например, `data_1`), исходную менять не нужно

Сделала по-другому:

```
cols_to_delete = df2.columns[df2.isna().sum() > 2]
df2.drop(cols_to_delete, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Что мне непонятно: как сделать задание по вышеуказанному алгоритму #1 - #4.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [23, 54, pd.np.nan, 87],
    'col2': [45, 39, 45, 32],
    'col3': [pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, 76, pd.np.nan,]
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [92]: df
Out[92]:
   col1  col2  col3
0  23.0    45   NaN
1  54.0    39   NaN
2   NaN    45  76.0
3  87.0    32   NaN
```

---

Решение 1:

```
In [93]: thresh = 2

In [94]: new = df.loc[:, df.isna().sum().le(thresh)]
```

Решение 2:

```
In [96]: new = df.drop(columns=df.columns[df.isna().sum() > thresh])
```

---

Результат:

```
In [95]: new
Out[95]:
   col1  col2
0  23.0    45
1  54.0    39
2   NaN    45
3  87.0    32
```